# I can't link the information from a database into my php document

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make an online shop for my school canteen (this is a school assignment) and I'm really struggling with linking items from the database I've created into my PHP document.

*This is the page I'm using for the store called* **canteen_ordering.php**

```
<!--MADE BY MIKE YAZDAN, NARRABUNDAH COLLEGE YEAR 12 - DYNAMIC WEB-->
<?php 
require_once('php/create_db.php');
require_once('./php/component.php'); 

$database = new CreateDb("productdb", "producttb");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="A Look at the IT Department">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Narrabundah, College, IT, Eagle">
        <meta name="author" content="Mike Yazdan">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/acd14a985b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Image Showcase</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <section class="page8">   <!--START PAGE 8-->

            <nav class="navBar">
                <img src="images/png/badge3.png" alt="Logo" class="ncLogo">

                <ul class="navContainer">   <!--NAV SELECTION START-->

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Canteen</a>
                        <ul class="child active">
                            <li><a href="hnf.html">HNF</a></li>
                            <li><a href="shdf.html">SHDF</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="detication_to_health.html">Detication To Health</a>
                        <ul class="child">
                            <li><a href="more_info.html">More Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="announcements.html">Canteen Announcments</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="canteen_ordering.html">Canteen Ordering</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>  <!--NAV SELECTION END-->

            <section class="canteenContainer">
                <img src="images/png/narrabundah.png" alt="eagle banner" class="bird">
                <section class="food box">
                    
                    <?php
                        $result = $database->getData();
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            component($row['product_name'], $row['product_price'], $row['product_image'], $row['id']);
                        }
                    ?>
                    
                <br>
                </section>
            </section>

        </section> <!--END PAGE 8-->

    </body>

</html>
```

*this is the page that stores PHP values in HTML* **component.php**

```
<?php

function component($productname, $productprice, $productimage){
    $element = "
    
    <div id=\"latte\" class=\"subCont\">
        <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\">
            <h3>$productname</h3>
            <img src=\"resources/images/png_jpg/$productimage\" alt=\"Latte\">
            <p class=\"text\">
           
                Macaroni and cheese—also called mac 'n' cheese in the United States, and 
                macaroni cheese in the United Kingdom—is a dish of cooked macaroni pasta 
                and a cheese sauce, most commonly cheddar. It can also incorporate other 
                ingredients, such as breadcrumbs or meat.
           
            </p>
            <div class=\"canBtnContainer\">
                <button type=\"submit\" name=\"add\" class=\"canBtn\">Add to Cart</button>
                <p>$$productprice</p>
            </div>
        <form>
    </div> 
    ";

}
```

*This is is the page that creates the database called* **create_db.php**

```
<?php

class CreateDb
{
        public $servername;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $dbname;
        public $tablename;
        public $con;

        // class constructor
    public function __construct(
        $dbname = "newdb",
        $tablename = "productdb",
        $servername = "localhost",
        $username = "root",
        $password = ""
    )
    {
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->tablename = $tablename;
        $this->servername = $servername;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

      // create connection
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

        // Check connection
        if (!$this->con){
            die("Connection failed : " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // query
        $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname";

        // execute query
        if(mysqli_query($this->con, $sql)){

            $this->con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // sql to create new table
            $sql = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename
                            (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                             product_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                             product_price FLOAT,
                             product_image VARCHAR (100)
                            );";

            if (!mysqli_query($this->con, $sql)){
                echo "Error creating table : " . mysqli_error($this->con);
            }

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    // get product from the database
    public function getData(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

*This is the database*
[items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OTGt.png)

*This is the database*
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxhBB.png)

*This is the*
[database name and table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjR5k.png)

Comment: Just replace `$element =` with `echo` in the `component` function because basically all you're trying to do is print it rather than store it in a variable.

Comment: AHAJHGJHQGKFK@JQ ok no I understand, I didn't even echo the $element variable in the component function. Thank you sherif‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

see first your table is created and function is able to fetch values,
then
you operating with many " quotations in function it makes confusion use single quote ' while using things inside statement/double quotes ,

use . concatenate two things

```
 <?php

function component($productname, $productprice, $productimage){
    $element = "
    
    <div id='latte' class='subCont'>
        <form action='index.php' method='post'>
            <h3>".$productname."</h3>

            <img src='resources/images/png_jpg/".$productimage."' alt='Latte'>
            <p class='text'>
           
                Macaroni and cheese—also called mac 'n' cheese in the United States, and 
                macaroni cheese in the United Kingdom—is a dish of cooked macaroni pasta 
                and a cheese sauce, most commonly cheddar. It can also incorporate other 
                ingredients, such as breadcrumbs or meat.
           
            </p>
            <div class='canBtnContainer'>
                <button type='submit' name='add' class='canBtn'>Add to Cart</button>
                <p>".$productprice."</p>
            </div>
        <form>
    </div> 
    ";

}


?>
```